# Получение доступа к управлению к окну через метод open

Tags: javascript

Открываю на странице окно сайта через метод open.

Можно ли как-то получить доступ к окну и вызывать методы работы с элементами на этом окне?

```
let mywindow = window.open(URL);
//Дальше какие-то операции с mywindow 
//к примеру 
mywindow.addEventListener("onload", () => {
//... 
})
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно.

В целом, код из вопроса и так делает то что вам нужно. Проблема в том, что `addEventListener` вешается не на то событие.

```js
let mywindow = window.open('https://ru.stackoverflow.com');

// onload заменён на load
mywindow.addEventListener("load", () => {
    console.log(mywindow.document.querySelector('title').innerText);
})
```

Так же стоит учитывать [Same-origin политику](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

[Window.open() | MDN en](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: Спасибо, получается что я могу в открытом окне повесить обработчики событий на различные элементы и они будут исполняться?

Comment: Да, вполне. В примере из ответа это и происходит.

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли

Answer (score 0):

Можно только в том случае, если открываемое окно принадлежит тому же домену, либо при открытии url  вообще не был указан.

При попытке сделать что-то лишнее будет происходить ошибка вроде

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://ru.stackoverflow.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Доступ к окну с протоколом `data:` таже будет считаться кроссдоменным.

Comment: А можно тогда как-нибудь управлять каким-то сайтом через скрипт, api у сайта нет, поэтому подумал, что могу через js вызывать события на сайте, симулируя пользователя, т.е. вместо того чтобы нажимать на кнопку вручную, нажатие происходило через скрипт

Comment: @АндрейПетров, с другого сайта? Нет. А если для себя, то сниппеты, браузерные расширения, селениум, электрон.